# Error al intentar hacer un rollback de una transacción desde java

Tags: java, postgresql, transacciones

Mi problema es que deseo hacer desde java una transacción con un update y una función dentro de la misma:

```
public void cambiarContrasena(String nombre, String password, String nuevo_password) throws SQLException {

    conex.getConexion().setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement ps1 = null, ps2 = null;
    try {
        String sql1 = "UPDATE usuarios SET password = ? WHERE password = ? ;";
        ps1 = conex.getConexion().prepareStatement(sql1);

        ps1.setString(1, nuevo_password);
        ps1.setString(2, password);
        ps1.executeUpdate();

        String sql2 = "SELECT agregarModificacion(?,?);";
        ps2 = conex.getConexion().prepareStatement(sql2);
        ps2.setString(1, nombre);
        ps2.setString(2, "Cambió su contraseña");
        ps2.executeUpdate();
        conex.getConexion().commit();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        conex.getConexion().rollback();
    } finally {
        if (ps1 != null) {
            ps1.close();
        }if (ps2 != null) {
            ps2.close();
        }
    }
}
```

y cuando la voy a correr me aparece lo siguiente:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Cannot rollback when autoCommit is enabled.
```

Alguien sabe a qué se debe esto?

Comment: ¿`getConexion()` devuelve siempre el mismo objeto de conexión, o cada vez uno nuevo?

Comment: jachguate gracias. Era algo que estaba haciendo muy de rutina a partir de haber visto un videotutorial por youtube, copiaba y pegaba esa forma de hacer la conexión en todoslos casos. Ahora mismo me voy a profundizar sobre la clase Connection en la api de java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando autocommit esta en true, cada sentencia de sql corre en un sola transacció y el commit lo hace la misma base de datos.

Para ejecutar una transacción con más de una sentencia necesitas poner autocommit en false y, usar la misma conexión para todas las sentencia (en tu código veo que querés ejecutar la segunda sentencia con una nueva conexión).

`conex.setAutocommit(false);` debe apagar el autocommit. Este seteo hacelo justo después de obtener la conexión.

El tema de no poder hacer rollback cuando autocommit está en on (true) es que cuando querés hacer el rollback desde java, la transacción ya está commiteada por la base de datos.

**Fe de erratas:**

No había leido bien el código y confundí `conex` con el objecto `Connection`, en realidad sería así:

```
Connection conn = conex.getConnection();
conn.setAutocomit(false);
```

Y usar `conn` para las setencias que participan en la transacción.
Finalmente hacer `conn.commit();` o `conn.rollback();` para cerrar la transacción.

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan. Mi problema fue no haber profundizado más sobre la clase Connection de java, entre otras cosas. Creé una única conexión esta vez y funcionó.